# js get index of form input array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding array inputs  by this code and also I have a button which on click I increase the number of rows

```
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="record" class="filled-in"></td>
<td><input type="text" class=" form-control" name="identity_number[]" id="identity_number[]"                                             
onchange="alert($(this).index());identity_number_change(this.value)" required></td>                                        
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name[]" id="first_name[]" required>                                            
</td>
```

$('#number_of_booking').change(function (event) {

```
            var count = $('#number_of_booking').val();
                $("#passengers_table tbody").empty();
                for (var n = 0; n < count; n++) {
                    var markup = "<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"record\" class=\"filled-in\"></td>"+
                        "<td><input type=\"text\" class=\" form-control\" name=\"identity_number[]\" id=\"identity_number[]\" onchange=\"alert($(this).index());identity_number_change(this.value)\" required></td>"+                                                                  
                        "<td><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"first_name[]\" id=\"first_name[]\" required></td>"+
                       </tr>";
                    $("#passengers_table tbody").append(markup);

            }            
    });
```

and in ajax I want to know what is the changing row by something like index 
my ajax code

```
function identity_number_change(identity_number){
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url:'{{url("hotel/transfers/find_passenger/")}}'+'/'+identity_number,
success:function(data){                                     
document.getElementById('first_name[]').value = data.first_name;
},
```

the problem is always its change only the first row I don't know how to say for example change first name in the same row of the change

Comment: ID is meant to be unique. You should not have multiple items with same id. A name of multiple form fields can be 'something[]' as an array but you still need a unique ID for each field for scripting purposes. That is why we use class, instead of id is such scenarios.

Comment: 1. use Template literals (Template strings) , we are in 2019 :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Please use scope for your case scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Actually I replace the array in id to get in each time an id increment by the loop as

```
for (var n = 0; n < count; n++) {
<input type=\"text\" class=\" form-control\" name=\"identity_number[]\" 
id=\"identity_number-"+n+"\" onchange=\"identity_number_change(this.value,this.id)\" 
required></td>"
```

and to find the id I use

```
var x = id.split('-');
document.getElementById('first_name-'+x[1]).value = data.first_name;
```